# how to bypass wildcard no match in shell command

Tags: csh, tcsh

I am trying to delete a few files like this:

```
rm -f x.txt b*.txt
```

This works if there are these files:

```
b1.txt x.txt
```

But if b1.txt does not exist, then this command will also not delete x.txt. It will simply give this error message and not delete **any** file:

```
rm: No match.
```

How to remove files even if some parts of the regex does not match?

Note: correction: yes, it was in csh not bash, I have updated the tag.

Comment: Set `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: That error message suggests you may be using tcsh instead of bash. They're very different shells, so please check what you're actually using, and adjust the tags appropriately. (Also, that's not a regex, it's a wildcard aka glob pattern.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson: thanks for catching it, yes this was for tcsh, not bash. I have updated the question.

Comment: @anubhava: Actually I am using \rm, which bypasses my alias. But the question remains, how do I delete the other items that are not matching the wildcard?

Comment: That will be `tcsh/csh` question not a `bash` or `regex` problem

Comment: There is no good/easy way to do this in tcsh as far as I know; you can use `set nonomatch`, which will leave the pattern unchanged if nothing matches so it becomes `x.txt b*.txt` instead of an error, but then you need to remove that `b*.txt` word from the list with a loop or something. Do you really *need* to use tcsh? It's kinda old and has lots of limitations; I would strongly recommend using zsh (which supports many (t)csh features) or bash if at all possible.

Comment: @MartinTournoij: Thanks. I normally use bash, but this was for a legacy project.